# expected identity upn connecting to service as network service,

Tags: wcf, authentication, spn, upn

We have a web application, running in an application pool as 'NETWORK SERVICE'.
The web application connects to a service (.svc) on another web server. The other web server also has the service hosted as 'NETWORK SERVICE'. I believe this is the default.

The following endpoint, when run anywhere else works perfectly.

```
<endpoint address="http://server123/UnitTrustService/UnitTrustService.svc"
  binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_UnitTrustService"
  contract="UnitTrustServiceReference.UnitTrustService" name="WSHttpBinding_UnitTrustService">
 <identity>
  <servicePrincipalName value="server123" />
 </identity>
</endpoint>
```

Unfortunately when executed from the web site, we get the following error.

```
        System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 
    The identity check failed for the outgoing message. 
    The expected identity is 'identity(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/right/possessproperty: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn)' 
for the 'http://server123/UnitTrustService/UnitTrustService.svc' target endpoint. 
Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Security.IdentityVerifier.EnsureIdentity(EndpointAddress serviceReference, AuthorizationContext authorizationContext, String errorString)...
```

Any ideas?
I have tried running this as local system on the web server machine with exactly the same configuration and it works perfectly.

It has something to do with IIS?

Regards
Craig.

Answer (score 4):

This probably indicates a problem with the **client's** web.config. Double-check the `<identity>` for the client. For instance, the following example snippet in your client's web.config might cause this exception if the service expected the identity to be `userPrincipalName` instead of `servicePrincipalName`. It's an easy distinction to miss that has caught me up before.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://server.domain.com/Services/DoSomething.svc" behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDoSomething" contract="Mycontract" name="WSHttpBinding_IDoSomething_Custom_AddSomething">
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="user@domain.com" />
```

Comment: yes, look at the response - it is saying it expected UPN. This is the UserPrincipalName. change servicePrincipalName to userPrincipalName. Another thing you can try is change the server.domain.com to IP address and see if this forces NTLM